Check if a predicate is satisfied on all tokens in LateX3 using conditionals
I am trying to write an expandable conditional that test if a condition is satisfied and it does not seem to work as expected.
Currently here is my approach (with \token_if_letter_p as an example of a condition):
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checkifletters}{mmm}{
    \check_if_letters:eTF{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \check_if_letters:n{p,T,F,TF}{
    \tl_map_function:nN{#1}\__check_if_letters_loop:n
    \prg_return_true:
}
\cs_new:Npn \__check_if_letters_loop:n #1{
    \bool_lazy_and:nnF{\tl_if_single_token_p:n{#1}}{\token_if_letter_p:N #1}{
        \tl_map_break:n{\prg_return_false:}
    }
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \check_if_letters:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\checkifletters{abcde}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % TRUE
\checkifletters{ab5e}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero
\checkifletters{ab{cd}e}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero
\end{document}

QUESTION: What is the way to do it in LaTeX3, in a reasonably fast way (avoiding unnecessary overhead at compile-time) and that is expandable?
ADDITIONAL QUESTION: Do I need to use \tl_if_single_token_p:n{#1} to "protect" the function against ill-behaved inputs that would make it crash, or will it work without it on a possible inputs?

your snippet can not be tested. Extend it to a complete example.

Now it can compile

How do you want the test to behave with things like \check_if_letters:nTF{a{b}c}{only letters}{not only letters} ? Or \check_if_letters:nTF{}{only letters}{not only letters}? Or \cs_new_eq:NN \Implicitb b \check_if_letters:nTF{a\Implicitb c}{only letters}{not only letters} ?

Your code cannot work, because you unconditionally issue \prg_return_true:.
You can add a special token at the end of the token list and check for it, so the functions know that the end has been reached without ever finding a nonletter.
The test about “single” is necessary, or a{bc} would fail.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \vincent_check_if_letters:n {p,T,F,TF}
  {
    \tl_map_function:nN { #1 \q_nil } \vincent__check_if_letters_loop:n
  }
\cs_new:Npn \vincent__check_if_letters_loop:n #1
  {
    \quark_if_nil:nTF {#1}
      {
        \prg_return_true:
      }
      {
        \bool_lazy_and:nnF
          { \tl_if_single_token_p:n {#1} }
          { \token_if_letter_p:N #1 }
          {
            \tl_map_break:n { \prg_return_false: }
          }
      }
  }

%\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \vincent_check_if_letters:n {e} {p,T,F,TF} % why?

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\iflettersTF}{mmm}
  {
    \vincent_check_if_letters:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\iflettersTF{abc}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\iflettersTF{}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\iflettersTF{123}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\iflettersTF{a@}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\iflettersTF{a{bc}}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\end{document}


I see no reason for the variant of the conditional.

You could put an unconditional \prg_return_true: after the end of the loop with the break condition as \use_i:nn \prg_return_false: and avoid the quark test

How to return false if the input token list contain spaces?

@Vincent Spaces are ignored by \tl_map_function:nN as explained in the manual.

@egreg I opened a subsequent question for spaces: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725953/17200

As long as you don't need to crank out implicit character tokens of category 11 (letter), the following might do the trick:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \checkifletters {
  \exp_args:Ne \check_if_letters:nTF 
}
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \check_if_letters:n{p,T,F,TF}{
  \tl_if_blank:nTF {#1}
    {\prg_return_false:}
    {\__check_if_letters_loop:n {#1}}
}
\cs_new:Nn \__check_if_letters_loop:n {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {\prg_return_true:} {
    \tl_if_head_eq_catcode:nNTF {#1} A 
    {
      \exp_args:Ne \__check_if_letters_loop:n {\tl_tail:n {#1}}
    }
    {\prg_return_false:}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\message{^^JTest 1: \checkifletters{abcde}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%
\message{^^JTest 2: \checkifletters{ab5e}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%
\message{^^JTest 3: \checkifletters{ab{cd}e}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%
\message{^^JTest 4: \checkifletters{ab{c}e}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%
\message{^^JTest 5: \checkifletters{ abce}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%
\message{^^JTest 6: \checkifletters{ab ce}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%
\message{^^JProbably:}%
\message{^^JTest 7: \checkifletters{}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%
\message{^^JBut:}%
\let\Implicita a
\let\Implicitb b
\let\Implicitc c
\let\Implicitd d
\let\Implicite e
\message{^^JTest 8: \checkifletters{\Implicita\Implicitb\Implicitc\Implicitd\Implicite}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%
\message{^^JTest 9: \checkifletters{a\Implicitb c\Implicitd e}{TRUE}{FALSE}}%

\stop

Console output:
pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> 
Test 1: TRUE 
Test 2: FALSE 
Test 3: FALSE 
Test 4: FALSE 
Test 5: FALSE 
Test 6: FALSE 
Probably: 
Test 7: FALSE 
But: 
Test 8: TRUE 
Test 9: TRUE )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.

