How to detect inner spaces at the document level forwarded to token lists in LaTeX3?
Unprotected spaces are not treated as items in token lists in LaTeX3. If I have some argument coming from the document/user level, and I would like to detect if this argument have an inner protected or unprotected space, how I would do it? (for example, is there a way to protect spaces before forwarding arguments to LaTeX3 functions)?
The example code (which does not work) I have is the following:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\hasinnerspace}{m m m}{
    \has_inner_space:eTF{\tl_trim_spaces:e{#1}}{#2}{#3}
}
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \has_inner_space:n{p,T,F,TF}{
    \tl_map_function:nN{#1\q_nil}\__has_inner_space_loop:n
}
\cs_new:Npn \__has_inner_space_loop:n #1{
    \quark_if_nil:nTF{#1}{\prg_return_false:}{
        \bool_lazy_and:nnT{\tl_if_single_token_p:n{#1}}{
            \token_if_space_p:N #1
        }{\tl_map_break:n{\prg_return_true:}}
    }
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \has_inner_space:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\hasinnerspace{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % should return FALSE (return FALSE: OK)
\hasinnerspace{ mytext }{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % should return FALSE (return FALSE: OK)
\hasinnerspace{my text}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % should return TRUE (but return FALSE: NOT OK)
\end{document}

EDIT added after the posted answer: I would prefer to do it in an expandable way
EDIT 2 after the posted answer: I do not need to look into brace groups

note you only need xparse in old latex releases

I get the feeling your questions are of the 'X-Y' variety: what's the bigger picture here? The previous one was about programmatic tokens, but you've now linked to basically 'text' (for which slower 'action' loops tend to be needed). It's hard to give a proper answer without knowing the overall target.

you really shouldn't change the question after posted answers,

What do you mean when using the term "protected/unprotected space"?


Unprotected spaces are not treated as items in token lists in LaTeX3.

interface3.pdf says:

A token list (explicit, or stored in a variable) can be seen either as a list of “items”, or a list of “tokens”. An item is whatever \use:n would grab as its argument [...] .

In this answer it is recommended to avoid mixing these two concepts of expl3 token list in the usage of token lists in one's programming work. Either use an expl3 token list as a list of items or use it as a list of tokens, but don't do both with the same expl3 token list.

If I have some argument coming from the document/user level, and I would like to detect if this argument have an inner protected or unprotected space, how I would do it?

In terms of vintage code you can do s.th. like this for expandably detecting the presence of explicit space tokens (␣10) and protected non-(line)breaking spaces (~13) that might as well be nested between curly braces:
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange, 
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBrace,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is an explicit character token 
%% of category 1 (begin group):
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has a leading
%%                        explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked does not have a
%%                        leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does not contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category 1 or 2 or 6:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category 1 or 2
%%                                or 6>}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[3]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#3{{}}#1#2}{}}{}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token-sequence-gobble-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and spit that out
%% nested in braces.
%%
%% Defines <token-sequence-gobble-macro> to remove <token sequence> which in the
%% token-stream must definitely follow the token <token-sequence-gobble-macro>.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#3{{##1}}}%
  \@ifdefinable#2{\def#2#3{}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% END OF PARAPHERNALIA
%%=============================================================================
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@EnbraceSpaceDelimited}%
                             {\UD@GobbleSpace}%
                             { }%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@EnbraceProtectedSpaceDelimited}%
                             {\UD@GobbleProtectedSpace}%
                             {~}%
\newcommand\UD@BracesToParentheses[1]{(#1)}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% This loops over the argument to detect whether there is more than one 
% accumulation of non-space tokens:
\newcommand\hasinnerspace[1]{%
  \romannumeral
  \hasinnerspaceloop{#1}{\UD@firstoftwo}{\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
\newcommand\hasinnerspaceloop[3]{%
  % #1 - remaining arg to check
  % #2 - switch amount of starts of accumulations of non-spaces found 
  %      \UD@firstoftwo - no start of an accumulation of non-spaces found so far
  %      \UD@secondoftwo - one start of an accumulation of non-spaces found so far
  % #3 - switch whether next non-space forms start of an accumulation of non-spaces
  %      \UD@firstoftwo - next non-space is not a start of an accumulation of non-spaces
  %      \UD@secondoftwo - next non-space is a start of an accumulation of non-spaces
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
    \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{ }{\UD@EnbraceSpaceDelimited}{%
      \expandafter\hasinnerspaceloop\expandafter{\UD@GobbleSpace#1}{#2}{\UD@secondoftwo}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{~}{\UD@EnbraceProtectedSpaceDelimited}{%
        \expandafter\hasinnerspaceloop\expandafter{\UD@GobbleProtectedSpace#1}{#2}{\UD@secondoftwo}%
      }{%
        #3\UD@firstoftwo#2{%
          \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
            \expandafter\hasinnerspaceloop\expandafter{\UD@BracesToParentheses#1}{#2}{#3}%
          }{%
            #3{%
              \expandafter\hasinnerspaceloop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}%
            }{%
              \expandafter\hasinnerspaceloop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{\UD@secondoftwo}%
            }{\UD@firstoftwo}%
          }%
        }{%
          \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{ mytext }{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{my text}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{m{y t}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{~mytext~}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{my~text}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{m{y~t}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{~ mytext ~}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{my ~ text}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{m{y ~ t}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{m{y{~t}}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{m{y{ ~ t}}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{~~}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{~ ~}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{ ~ ~ }{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{ ~{} ~ }{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\hasinnerspace{}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%

\end{document}

Console output:
pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux) 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
FALSE ; expected: FALSE (./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.


(for example, is there a way to protect spaces before forwarding arguments to LaTeX3 functions)?

In the context of using expl3 token lists as lists of items, whereby explicit space tokens between items are ignored and whereby an outermost level of curly braces surrounding an entire item of the token list stack, if present, is stripped off when retrieving that item, you can loop over the argument, wrapping list items in curly braces, cranking out leading explicit space tokens via \tl_if_head_is_space:nTF and explicitly adding items consisting of explicit space tokens wrapped in curly braces:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\use:n{\cs_new:Npn \MyStuff_gobblespace:w}~ {}
\cs_new:Nn \MyStuff_outermostexplicitspacetokensinbraces:n
  {\exp_not:o {\exp:w \__MyStuff_outermostexplicitspacetokensinbraces:nn {#1}{}}}
\cs_new:Nn \__MyStuff_outermostexplicitspacetokensinbraces:nn 
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{\exp_end: #2}{
      \tl_if_head_is_space:nTF {#1} {
        \exp_args:No \__MyStuff_outermostexplicitspacetokensinbraces:nn {\MyStuff_gobblespace:w #1}{#2{~}}
      }{
        \exp_args:Nee
        \__MyStuff_outermostexplicitspacetokensinbraces:nn {\tl_tail:n{#1}}{ \exp_not:n{#2}{\tl_head:n{#1}}}
      }
    }
  }

% Code for testing:

\msg_new:nnnn {MyStuff} {Report} {#1} {too~lazy~to~fill~this~out}
\tl_new:N \g_MyStuff_scratch_tl
\cs_new:Nn \MyStuff_string:n {^^JItem:~{\tl_to_str:n {#1}}}
\cs_new:Npn \ExpandAndSetAndShowScratchtl #1
  {
    \exp_args:Nnnx
    \msg_term:nnn{MyStuff} {Report} {^^JWill~now~map~the~items~of~the~token~list~stack~without~outermost~spaces~in~braces:
      \tl_map_tokens:nn {#1} {\MyStuff_string:n}
    }
    
    \exp_args:Nnnx
    \msg_term:nnn{MyStuff} {Report} {^^JWill~now~map~the~token~list~stack~with~outermost~spaces~in~braces:
      \exp_args:Ne
      \tl_map_tokens:nn {\MyStuff_outermostexplicitspacetokensinbraces:n{#1}} {\MyStuff_string:n}
    }

    \tl_gset:Nn \g_MyStuff_scratch_tl {#1}
    \exp_args:Nnnx
    \msg_term:nnn{MyStuff} {Report} {^^JWill~now~map~the~content~of~the~token~list~variable~stack~without~outermost~spaces~in~braces:
      \tl_map_tokens:Nn \g_MyStuff_scratch_tl {\MyStuff_string:n}
    }

    \tl_gset:Nx \g_MyStuff_scratch_tl {\MyStuff_outermostexplicitspacetokensinbraces:n{#1}}
    \exp_args:Nnnx
    \msg_term:nnn{MyStuff} {Report} {^^JWill~now~map~the~content~of~the~token~list~variable~stack~with~outermost~spaces~in~braces:
      \tl_map_tokens:Nn \g_MyStuff_scratch_tl {\MyStuff_string:n}
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExpandAndSetAndShowScratchtl{ A B C }

\stop

Console output:
pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

Will now map the items of the token list stack without outermost spaces in
braces:
Item: {A}
Item: {B}
Item: {C}

Will now map the token list stack with outermost spaces in braces:
Item: { }
Item: {A}
Item: { }
Item: {B}
Item: { }
Item: {C}
Item: { }

Will now map the content of the token list variable stack without outermost
spaces in braces:
Item: {A}
Item: {B}
Item: {C}

Will now map the content of the token list variable stack with outermost
spaces in braces:
Item: { }
Item: {A}
Item: { }
Item: {B}
Item: { }
Item: {C}
Item: { }
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.


We can implement this task using TeX primitives only.
\catcode`~=12
\def\isinnerspace#1{\expandafter\isinnerA\detokenize{#1}\end}
\def\isinnerA#1\end{\expandafter\isinnerC\expanded{\isinnerB#1~{}} \end}
\def\isinnerB #1~#2{#1\ifx^#2^\else \space \expandafter\isinnerB\expandafter#2\fi}
\def\isinnerC#1{\ifx\end#1 \isinnerF \else \expandafter \isinnerD \fi}
\def\isinnerD#1 #2{\ifx\end#2 \isinnerF \else \isinnerT \fi}
\def\isinnerF #1\fi #2#3{\fi #3}  % false
\def\isinnerT #1\end #2#3{\fi #2} % true
\catcode`~=13

\newlinechar=`^^J
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{ mytext }{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{my text}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{m{y t}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{~mytext~}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{my~text}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{m{y~t}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{~ mytext ~}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{my ~ text}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{m{y ~ t}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{m{y{~t}}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{m{y{ ~ t}}ext}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: TRUE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{~~}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{~ ~}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{ ~ ~ }{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{ ~{} ~ }{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%
\message{^^J\isinnerspace{}{TRUE}{FALSE} ; expected: FALSE}%

\bye

The pdftex creates this log file:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdftex 2023.2.20)  11 SEP 2024 14:50
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**pok
(./pok.tex 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
TRUE ; expected: TRUE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE 
 FALSE ; expected: FALSE )
No pages of output.

The macro \isinnerB replaces ~ to spaces. The macro \isinnerC checks in the given string includes spaces only (or nothing): the #1 has no separator, i.e the spaces are skipped to the \end by internal TeX rule. The macro \isinnerD skips to the first space and ignores next spaces when reading #2. If it is \end then there is no inner spaces else there is inner spaces.

\isinnerspace: Are you a sinner from space?

You can use tl_if_in  but as shown here you may need to trim first if you really only care about inner spaces.

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\hasspace#1{\tl_if_in:nnTF{#1}{~}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\hasspace{abc}{yes 1}{no 1}

\hasspace{ab c}{yes 2}{no 2}

\hasspace{abc }{yes 3}{no 3}


\end{document}



\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\hasspace#1{\exp_args:Ne\tl_if_in:nnTF{\tl_trim_spaces:e{#1}}{~}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\hasspace{abc}{yes 1}{no 1}

\hasspace{ab c}{yes 2}{no 2}

\hasspace{abc }{yes 3}{no 3}


\end{document}


How to make it expandable since \tl_if_in:nnTF is not?

@Vincent you didn't mention that in the question also you were not exactly clear whetehr the test should be before or after expansion. If \foo is abc xyz  then if you have  \def\one{\foo}  does that have a space? would it have a space if \protected\def\two{\foo} (which does not expand in an e argument.) does it matter if the space is inside a brace group (testing expandably for a space is easiest if you don't look inside brace groups)

I'm confused. generally spaces aren't a problem in user input, are they? (I mean, not more of a problem in expl3.) only if you start taking it apart, then you have to do something. but doesn't it then matter how you're taking it apart and what you're doing with it afterwards? I mean just because spaces are ignored in the code, doesn't mean they're ignored in the document?

@cfr ignoringspacesinadocumentwouldbeverystrangeiagree

@cfr If you map using \tl_map_..., then spaces will be dropped - so for example \text_map_... don't use \tl_map_... internally. But without an idea what's actually going on, I'm not sure if this is a true issue or not.

@JosephWright I'd count that as taking the input apart ....

If it's a simple if-contains test and you want to set it up expandable, you might be interested in the etl package:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% variant finding spaces not contained in braces (lightning fast)
\etl_new_if_in:Nnn \vincent_if_contains_space:n { ~ } { TF, T, F, p }

% variant searching also inside brace groups (comparatively slow!)
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \vincent_if_contains_space_deep:n #1 { TF, T, F, p }
  {
    \etl_if_in_deep:nnTF {#1} { ~ }
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \hasinnerspace { m m m }
  { \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \vincent_if_contains_space:nTF {#2} {#3} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\hasinnerspace{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % should return FALSE (return FALSE: OK)
\hasinnerspace{ mytext }{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % should return FALSE (return FALSE: OK)
\hasinnerspace{my text}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % should return TRUE (but return FALSE: NOT OK)
\end{document}

